# pagination codeigniter cant displaying images & css

Tags: css, pagination

I tried a lot but cant seem to figure out this, any help appreciated.my pagination in codeigniter work perfectly on the first page but when i go to the other pages , images don't display neither css. It seems that codeigniter doesnt recognize links to my assets folder.
Here is my code :

```
public function index()
{
    $config['base_url']='http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/program/index';
    $config['total_rows']=$this->listeprogram->count();
    $config['per_page']=12;
    $config['first_link'] = 'Première page';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Dernière page';
    $config['next_link']='Suivante';
    $config['prev_link']='Précédente';  
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data = array();
    $data['rows'] = $this->db->get('programs',$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(10));
}
```

Comment: I've solve the problem by creating an Assets Helper whith functions for css, images , videos , js ...